# How to make a tab unfocusable[Not selectable] in TabLayout - ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have implemented scrollable view with TabLayout, ViewPager and Fragments.

What I am trying to achieve- I don't want one of the tab to receive focus[Not through scrolling or click on tab in TabLayout] But I want to receive click on the tab. [Like a button]

I have tried adding fragment's views [which I want to be focused] in addFocusables method but it's not working.

```
viewPager.addFocusables();
```